# const_cast doesn't work c++?

Tags: c++, const-cast

I have the following code :

```
const int k=1;
    int *p=const_cast<int *>( &k);
    cout<<"k before="<<*p<<endl;
    *p=10;
    *const_cast<int *>( &k)=12;
    cout<<"k after="<<k<<endl;
```

the output was :

```
k before=1
k after=1
```

why doesn't const cast work here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const_cast` is normally used when/if you receive a `const` pointer to an object that wasn't originally defined as `const`. If (as in your case) the object was originally defined as `const`, attempting to modify it causes undefined behavior. Without the `const_cast`, the compiler won't let you even try to do that (the code won't compile).

A cast, however, tells the compiler you're sure you know what you're doing and it's really safe, so the compiler just needs to shut up and do what you told it instead of giving any error/warning messages like it might usually do. Unfortunately, in this case what you're doing is *not* really safe, but since you've told the compiler to shut up and do it, you won't get any warning about it (at least with most compilers).

As to what you should do, it comes down to deciding whether your `k` is really const or not. If you really need to modify it, then you need to define it as a normal (non-`const`) variable. If you want to ensure that only a small amount of specific code can modify it, then you could/can (for one possibility) make it private to a small class:

```
class my_int { 
    int k;
public:
    my_int() : k(1) {}

    do_mod() { k = 10; }

    operator int() { return k; }
};
```

Now, `do_mod` can modify `k` directly. Other code can use a `my_int` object as if it were an `int`, but can't modify its value -- in essence, it acts like an rvalue.

In fairness, I should probably point out that if it *really* tries by doing some casting, other code *can* modify the value of `k`. As Bjarne has said, C++'s protection mechanism is intended to prevent accidents, not intentional subversion.

Answer (score 12):

`const_cast` causes *[undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviour-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-ab)* if you cast away `const` then write to the value. Not doing anything is valid behaviour, as you have seen here.

In your particular example, what has likely happened is that the compiler sees that `k` is declared with the `const` storage class, knows that it can't (legally) change, and replaces

```
cout<<"k after="<<k<<endl;
```

with

```
cout<<"k after="<<1<<endl;
```

If you turn off optimisations you may (or may not) get a different result.

The very reason that casting away `const` invokes undefined behaviour is so that the compiler is free to do optimisations like this. If `const` variables could be freely cast to non-`const` variables and written to, then `const` would be absolutely meaningless to the compiler.

Comment: The compiler can choose to put `const` objects in read-only memory, in which case this program could crash with an access violation.

Comment: Causes undefined behavior if you cast away constness from an object that that is defined as const. If you cast away constness from a reference that points at an object that is not cost not so much.

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is **Undefined Behaviour**.  You cannot attempt to modify a variable that is `const`

Comment: It's actually "attempting to modify" the object that was originally `const` that's undefined behavior, not `const_cast`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I changed my answer

Comment: The object `k` isn't merely "originally const". It's const, it has been since it was created, and it will be as long as its lifetime extends. You cannot attempt to modify an object (including variables) that *is* const.